# How to create parent class to element id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

From

```
<div id="ball">
</div>
```

Create

```
<div class="grass">
    <div id="ball">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using jQuery but I was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) :

```
$('#ball').wrap('<div class="grass" />');
```

Comment: Simple but great answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of your question in comment but you can wrap around an identified image : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/amLte/

Comment: Thanks your answer worked great but for some reason the color is not overlaying in the overlay element here http://jsfiddle.net/aXMZD/3/. Do you have any ideas why the color isn't displaying? Should I create a new question? Thanks again for your help

Comment: The color is behind the image. Just add a padding : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/ukXm5/

Comment: I am trying to create the same affect as http://jsfiddle.net/aXMZD/ . Do you have any ideas how this can be accomplished (if possible) ?

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do. wrapping the element wouldn't help. You'd better make another question with your exact goal (adding a half transparent div *over* an image, if I guess right).

Comment: In fact, I think you want this : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/jSNDs/ (no need to wrap at all...)

Comment: Hard to answer why it works... I'd suggest you try to change it a little and see what happens.